# Customizing ViewPagerIndicator Tabs (All of them appears on the screen?)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am using `ViewPagerIndicator` in my project. Can I customize ViewPagerIndicator from "img1" to "img2" which are shown at below? I googled it but there is no info for that or can you suggest something to show all tabs on the screen without using actionbar bar?

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do try some other alternatives.

The PagerSlidingTabStrip library with the attribute pstsShouldExpand set to true or;

The SlidingTabsBasic android sample but with the modification used by the open sourced Google I/O 2014 app that includes the method setDistributeEvenly which you have to set to true.